# How to politely and indirectly tell someone they forgot to do something?

Tags: word-choice, politeness, phrase-requests

Let's say someone who's above me, like a teacher or a boss, forgot to do something. How would I notify them without being rude?

I only know the basic "~するのを忘れました"(though I'm not even sure if that's correct), but I want to be a bit more humble and roundabout.

I would appreciate if you could give me multiple different ways to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53942/please-help-with-this-text/53944#53944

Comment: I guess it really depends on who you are interacting with. But just by scanning through many articles online, it seems many people believe the most Japanese way is to not point it out at all.

Comment: Actually, perhaps this link can be of use: http://u-note.me/note/47497375#link0 . In summary, rather than highlighting the mistake, refer to what you think may be wrong, and then gently suggest that it be rechecked. For example「○○は□□ではないでしょうか？恐れ入りますが、ご確認お願い致します」

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you humbly inquire whether they have done it already,
or humbly state that it hasn't been done yet.

So if your boss forgot to reply to an email from last week, you could say something like,

> 「もうメールにお返事されましたか」
>
> "Have you already replied to (the) email?"

or

> 「先方からのメールにはまだお返事頂いていないそうです。」
>
> "It seems that the client hasn't received a response yet."

(be sure to trail off with a long pause and make your face look real worried...)

- To avoid being rude, you should try to point out that ***something hasn't happened yet*** and avoid *"assuming"* that they forgot ;)

Also, for bonus points try to look and ask them if **you** can do the thing they forgot.

> 「先方からのメールにお返事させて頂いてもよろしいでしょうか」
>
> "May I reply to the email from the client?"

(this is more effective if you appear to be out of breath...)